# I need help identifying and fixing a problem with fade-in text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating an introduction page to a little game of mine and I want the text to fade in after a short delay, but it won't appear.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("welcome").className = "show";
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("to").className = "show";
  }, 2500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("title").className = "show";
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("subtitle").className = "show";
  }, 4000);
};
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 1s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity linear 1s;
} // changed visibility to opacity on Jon Warren's suggestion
```

```html
<div id="welcome-text">
  <span id="welcome" class="hide">Welcome...</span><br/>
  <span id="to" class="hide">to</span>
  <p id="title" class="hide">[TITLE]</p>
  <p id="subtitle" class="hide">a choose your own adventure game.</p>
</div>
```

I expected the result to be the text fading in one line at a time (the fade provided by my css code, and the actual appearing by the js code) but instead the text gets stuck in the `.hide` class.

also, is there a way to make the js code more concise?

Comment: Have you taken a look at your developer console? Your snippet itself throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: every setTimeout does not need a semicolon at the end? I'm wondering why you put it inside the )

Comment: @esqew yeah i saw that! but i'm not sure where there's one missing. i've looked into it, but i just don't see the missing bracket.

Comment: since my note keeps getting removed: hi, i'm relatively new to js, haven't built much more than simple 100-line programs, and i'm rarely 100% sure what's wrong. i have been learning to code all on my own so i don't have someone to just ask about these things. thanks for any help you can give! :+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your javascript is a little broken. The semi-colon that you put at the end of your timeouts should actually go outside of the parentheses, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("welcome").className = "show";
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("to").className = "show";
  }, 2500);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("title").className = "show";
  }, 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("subtitle").className = "show";
  }, 4000);
};
```

Secondly, visibility isn't a ranging property, meaning that it doesn't know what's in between visible and hidden. You could use opacity though, try this instead:

```
.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity linear 1s;
}
.show {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity linear 1s;
}
```